# RSS to KML Overlay

Tags: google-maps, overlay, kml, geotagging

I'm want to display my blog as a Google Map overlay (each post contains geotags). How can I dynamically create a KML overlay from an RSS? Or better, how can I create a loop (PHP) that would display map placemarks according to given geotags?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Converting from one XML format to another XML format? Sounds like a job for [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT)!

Then again, I’ve just noticed that the Google Maps API seems to accept RSS as well: http://googlemapsapi.blogspot.com/2007/03/kml-and-georss-support-added-to-google.html